# Why can't I search my CloudKit records in the CloudKit Dashboard?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I added CloudKit functionality to an app I had made and I had two types of records, one of them (Speaker) had 1.7k records and the other (Speech) had 6k records. It’s been a few weeks since I was able to work with that data, but I could successfully query it from the app as well as search in the CloudKit dashboard. I just tried to search the records online again in the CloudKit dashboard and it says, for both Speech and Speaker records, ‘No records found containing the word “a”.’

Can anyone tell me why my CloudKit records are no longer searchable through the CloudKit Dashboard?

[image: Records exists in CK Dashboard]

Comment: There are definitely Speaker records in the database with a fullName field (the only one we can see in your image with the Search index ticked) that contain the string you are searching for? You are working in the development environment here, when you run your app it is not pointing to the Production environment is it? As an asside, you are aware that data you create in the Development environment will not be copied to Production when you switch?

Comment: Yes, I've tried switching form Development to Production mode, so I'm aware that the data isn't copied. I assume that my app is pointing to the Development environment because I can still successfully perform queries in code.

Comment: It may be important to note that I created two different apps with different tasks to help me import data to CloudKit. I realized that the app name and ID need to be set very carefully to make them work — I had to manually set the CKContainer in the 2nd app to get it to work because I still haven't got it right yet — and this is the only thing that's changed on CloudKit since I could query online a few weeks ago.